# Deriving Geometric Brownian Motion's solution?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

The Black Scholes model assumes the following underlying dynamics, known as Geometric Brownian Motion: $$dS_t=S_t(\mu dt+\sigma dW_t)$$

Then the solution is given: $$S_t=S_0\,e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t+\sigma W_t}$$

It can be shown by Ito Lemma on function $f(t,W_t)=\ln S_t$ that this solution is correct as it leads to above dynamics.

*But how do we solve the above SDE originally to find this solution?*

Guessing the above solution to apply Ito seems unlikely to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By applying Ito's Lemma on $f(t,x) = \ln x$ we get
$$d(\ln S_t) = \frac{1}{S_t}dS_t - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{S_t^2}dS_tdS_t$$
Substituting the expression for $dS_t$ we obtain
$$d(\ln S_t) = (\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)dt + \sigma dW_t$$

This is an expression that you can integrate in a straightforward way if you know $\mu$ and $\sigma$. That leads to the expression for $S_t$ you had in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Although very few SDEs have exact solutions, those that do are often found using some ansatz -- as is common for deterministic ODEs.

Without making the a priori choice of $\ln(S_t)$ you would use an ansatz like

$$S_t = X_te^{\sigma W_t},$$

where $X_t$ is a deterministic function.  Apply Ito's lemma to $f(t,w) = A_te^{\sigma w}.$  Then

$$d(X_te^{\sigma W_t}) = \frac{dX_t}{dt}e^{\sigma W_t}dt + \sigma X_te^{\sigma W_t}dW_t+\frac1{2}\sigma^2X_te^{\sigma W_t}dt.$$

Comparing with the SDE for $S_t$, we find

$$\frac1{X_t}\frac{dX_t}{dt}+\frac1{2}\sigma^2= \mu,$$

with solution

$$ X_t = X_0e^{(\mu - \frac1{2}\sigma^2)t}.$$

Then $S_0 = X_0e^{\sigma W_0}=X_0$ and the solution is

$$ S_t = S_0e^{(\mu - \frac1{2}\sigma^2)t}e^{\sigma W_t}.$$

Comment: I solve the differential equation from the beginning. T is the maturation time of the credit. In the Vasicek model the solution is the same except that there is an exponent term that is $\sqrt{T}$ obtained $e^{\sigma W_t \sqrt{T}}$. Do you know how to get that missing term in this case?