# Show Geometric Brownian motion is the unique solution to $\frac{dS_t}{S_t}=\mu dt+\sigma dW_t$.

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Given
$$
X_t=\sigma W_t+\mu t,
$$
the SDE
$$
\frac{dS_t}{S_t}=\mu dt+\sigma dW_t
$$
has a unique solution
$$
Z_t=\exp\Big(X_t-\frac{1}{2}\langle X\rangle_t\Big).
$$
We know from various posts and textbooks (e.g. [Deriving Geometric Brownian Motion's solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873704/deriving-geometric-brownian-motions-solution)) that $Z_t$ is a solution.
To show uniqueness, I want to apply Ito's formula to $R_t=Z_t'/Z_t$, where $Z_t$,$Z_t'$ are two solutions, then
$$
dR_t=-\frac{Z_t'}{Z_t^2}dZ_t+\frac{1}{Z_t}dZ_t'+\frac{Z_t'}{Z_t^3}d\langle Z\rangle_t-\frac{1}{Z_t^2}d\langle Z,Z' \rangle_t.
$$
The first two terms cancel out as $dZ_t=Z_tdX_t$, but how can we deal with the last two terms? In particular, is it possible to conclude some relationships between
$d\langle Z,Z' \rangle_t$ and $d\langle X \rangle_t$?

Comment: $d\langle Z\rangle_t = \sigma^2 Z_t^2 dt$ and  $d\langle Z,Z'\rangle_t = \sigma^2 Z_tZ'_t dt$, so the last two terms being subtracted are both equal to $\sigma^2 R_t^2 dt$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Why the quadratic variation is of the form $d\langle Z\rangle_t=\sigma^2Z_t^2dt$, is that by approximating the quadratic variation by infinite sum and applying mean value theorem?

Comment: It's because $Z$ satisfies the SDE $dZ_t = \mu Z_t dt+\sigma Z_t dW_t$, so the martingale part of $Z$ is $\sigma \int_0^t Z_s dW_s$.